# How to fix wrong display of components inside 'TableLayout' on different screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I am making a layout for MainScreen of an app using `TableLayout` and I want to set 6  square `Button`s inside `TableLayout` (3 rows, 2 `Button`s inside each of them).
`Button`s are supposed to be placed with the same spacing between and have the same size.
The problem is that I can't make it look like I want, because `layout` looks different on different screen resolutions.
I know it may be normal behaviour, but I have no idea how to position layout correctly.

Is there any workarround instead of making different XML files for different resolutions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_site_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainScreenActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helloText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/alfa_slab_one"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Witaj "
        android:textColor="@color/mdtp_white"
        android:textSize="23sp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp">

        <TableRow>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/badge_layout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_button1"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Otrzymane" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badge_notificationTopLeft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout1"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                    android:text="37"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/badge_layout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_button2"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Zaakceptowane" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badge_notificationTopRight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout2"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                    android:text="16"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/badge_layout3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_button3"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                        android:text="W trakcie" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badge_notificationCenterLeft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout3"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/badge_layout4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_button4"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"
                        android:text="Zakończone"

                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badge_notificationCenterRight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout4"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/badge_layoutBottomLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_button5"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"
                        android:text="Zdjęcia" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badge_notificationBottomLeft"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout5"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/badge_layout6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/main_button6"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dip"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Wyjdź" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/badge_notificationBottomRight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_layout6"
                    android:background="@drawable/item_count"
                    android:text="20"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fullListHolder">
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/acceptedListHolder">
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Results:**

Galaxy J4+:
[image]

Galaxy J6 2018:
[image]

Galaxy S5:
[image]

Galaxy S7:
[image]

Comment: Please upload all image here only.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post.

Comment: Use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/), its very easy and very responsive, in your example you are giving fixed size to your views - different phone got different screen size and this is why you will see different display on differant phones.
 **here is an example for a layout that looks like you need:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button5" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="424dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="423dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Tamir and @Pratik. I've tried to use it earlier, but I didn't understand how it could be easier to use, and more efficient, cause of lots of hardcoded values. But it seems like it's easier to manipulate with it in `design` view. I was always coding raw XML, so I'll try this approach :) .

Comment: work from the design if you can , its just more comfortable